# Is the webhooks logo actually a logo for webhooks?

Tags: webhooks

When I look into webhooks, I come across this image
[image]

Is this the universal logo for webhooks? I noticed companies will use it to represent webhooks, but I cannot find information about who created the logo and why it looks this way. Curious if anyone can use this as the logo for webhooks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel it does not fall under the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the source is this repo on Github: https://github.com/logo/webhooks

Various projects and libraries have included the logo, but there is no official standard.